# Cordova Push Notification - pass information into app when clicked?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I am making a Cordova app and I am looking for a way to somehow capture that my app was started from clicking on the push notification. That's pretty easy in native Java, but is it possible in Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [plug-in](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) that simplify that, in Cordova you must implement a plug-in (yours or from a third) if you want interaction with the native side.

In this case you could use the `onNotificationOpen` event to listen the body of the notification.

You must also, have a firebase project to link and download the `Google-services.json` (BTW firebase can work with APNS too)